# NumPy/SciPy return array indexes vectorized?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization

For instance binary erosion manipulates and return over ndarray. Basically I am trying to avoid iteration and use more of an image approach. e.g. a function that takes

```
[[a, b, c], [1, 2, 3]]
```

returns

```
[[0, 0, a], [0, 1, b], etc.
```

without iterating

Comment: Huh?  What exactly is the connection between your input and your output?  What is your question?

Comment: `numpy` 'vectorization' means using compiled methods to do the iterations faster - at compiled speeds rather than interpreted python speed.

Comment: question is basically which scipy/numpy function(s) should I be using. Yea I mean without having to iterate in base python or equivalent stuff like ndenumerate which is slower for my application. I just want to do pixel manipulation like a falling sand simulation or something like that

Comment: If I look at any numpy 'guide' it tells me to iterate over an ndarray with a for loop which is less efficient than just using python arrays - to capitalize on the increased performance. I am just looking for the basic vectorized functions I don't know why they are so obscured even in the docs.

Comment: Look at other SO questions with [numpy] tag and 'vectorize' or 'eliminate for loops' in the title - and one or more accepted answers.  That should give you more of an idea of the issues.  All array methods and operators are 'vectorized'..But how you use them might not be.